# TeamCity API setting configuration parameters

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0

I have configuration parametr **current_build_date** (User Defined Parameter) I want just to set this parameter to current date by API TeamCity.

On docs I have seen this:

```
http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildTypeLocator>/parameters/<parameter_name>
```

I know my **Build configuration ID**, but I can't understand how by this to make **buildTypeLocator**.

I assume result will be something like this:

```
 curl -u Login:Password \
      -X PUT \
      -d 'valueOfMyParam' \
      -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
      http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildTypeLocator>/parameters/current_build_date
```

I will realy appreciate if somebody who knows TeamCity API will help me with this problem.

I made attempt just to pass instead of buildTypeLocator my Build configuration ID and I got ERROR:

```
[17:08:25][Step 3/3] Error has occurred during request processing (Not Found).
[17:08:25][Step 3/3] Error: jetbrains.buildServer.server.rest.errors.NotFoundException: No project found by name or internal/external id 'BuildConfigurationID'.
```

If there are any problems or ambiguities with my question please add comment, i'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you browse the REST API endpoints in a browser you'll be able to see the format of the build locator.

Visit `http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/` and you'll see the entries have a href attribute that contains the buildLocator (generally a property:value combination)

[image]

You'll then be able to navigate using that url / communicate via the API

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem: build type locator was **id:Build configuration ID**

```
current_build_date=`date +%%Y-%%m-%%d:%%H:%%M:%%S` 
echo $current_build_date;
curl -u Login:Password \
              -X PUT \
              -d $current_build_date \
              -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
              https://teamcity.billing.ru/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:Build

configuration ID/parameters/current_build_date
```